# SQL Server to MySQL conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, pagination, sp-executesql

I need help to convert this part of stored procedure from MSSQL to MYSQL, any suggestion is appreciated.

P.s. Sorry for my English

```
     set @PARAMS = '@DATA_INIZIO VARCHAR(20), 
           @DATA_FINE VARCHAR(20), 
           @SEDE VARCHAR(10)'


 set @CMD = 'WITH DriversRN AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+ @ORDER_BY_RN +') as ROW_NUM, * FROM digitalpodcontrol 
        WHERE Date BETWEEN @DATA_INIZIO AND @DATA_FINE AND Depot = @SEDE
    )
    SELECT * FROM DriversRN
    WHERE ROW_NUM BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@MIN__VALUE) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@MAX__VALUE) + ' 
    ORDER BY ' + @ORDER_BY + ' ' + @DIRECTION

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @CMD, @PARAMS, @DATA_INIZIO, @DATA_FINE, @SEDE
```